# Direct link to sample data?

Tags: magento-1.9, sample-data, download-link

Is there a direct link to the sample data for CE 1.9.1/1.9.2?

I'm trying to download it directly to the servers using `wget` but the links on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ht_magento-ce-sample.data.html are broken and the normal download page has a user interface that hides the link.

My local internet connection is slow enough for the download to take about 20 minutes and the upload will probably take well over an hour.

Comment: Links are definitely dead, maybe you should try using the magerun to install sample data: http://n98-magerun.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands/standalone.html Not sure if it works as if the command is using the same links, it'll fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both 1.9.1 and 1.9.2 use the same sample data package.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mageloads/files/assets/1.9.1.0/magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

There is also this project which contains highly optimised (compressed) sample data https://github.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data